# Could baby superman or Supergirl land on Earth today in their spaceship and not be detected before arriving on Earth?

Tags: aliens, space-travel, spaceships

In EVERY Superman origin story, we see always see the same thing with Superman and later his cousin arriving on earth in their auto piloted ship.
Their spaceship is then found either by a loving couple or by Superman himself and the rest is history.

But lets say this happened in modern day society and a small spaceship, was rocketing towards the planet Earth from the edges of our solar system.
the ship was on autopilot and didn´t make any effort to hide its presence, the ships computer was only interested in landing safely on Earth.
Would that ship actually be able to land on Earth undetected and little Kal-El would still be raised in Kansas, or would various astronomers, military organisations have discovered that ship, days if not months before it landed on Earth resulting in little Kal-El growing up in area 51?

Comment: There is a plethora of answers to this question. Both in theory (on why it would not be detected) and in practice (with the latest proof from 2013 and Chelyabinsk meteor).

Comment: Yes but any ships flying towards earth from another solar system would need to make several adjustments under way even in our solar system, wouldn´t such small burst of heat at regular intervals trigger every early warning systems watching space? 
Meteors are just large rocks that just goes where gravity leads them, they don´t perform several corrections and such like a space ship would.

Comment: I'd say you first need to explain how their faster then light travel system worked.  They clearly are using something more then rocket propulsion for superman to reach Earth from Krypton and still be a baby.  Given the handwave magic technology required for the rocket to even reach Earth you could make any claim you want about how easy it is to detect.  Maybe it came out of hyperspace a few hundred meters above the surface of the earth and be nearly impossible to detect, and maybe it has such massive acceleration that it's setting off every radar out there; who knows?

Comment: @Gridlock Using gravity is exactly what spaceships does. It don't require using own fuel and you just need to calculate it. Something that alien spaceship would be capable of.

Comment: Also to "see" burst of energy someone would need to know where to look and what to look for. And then be able to calcualte path and follow the object.

Answer (score 1):

The TV show *Smallville* did actually explore this as a theme in the series.  To get around the early warning detection systems that would have been in place in the 1989 setting of Superman's ship crashing, the series has the ship impact in a metor shower created by fragments of Krypton which included the ship in it's fragments. While the public story was about the meteorite impacts in a small town in the American Heartlands, Clark was quietly adopted by the Kents, who were the closest to his ship's impact. It was later learned that Kara Kent, Supergirl, was also in this shower but her ship crashed in a reservoir behind a dam and was in suspended animation until Clark accidentally released her in the 6-7th season cliffhangers (Kara being older than Clark when Krypton blew up was a new aspect to the mythos that was introduced around the same time in the comics when the character was reintroduced into the canon).

Additionally, in the 4-5 season cliffhanger, a Kryptonian broadcast from earth brought a third ship (in the story progression it was at the time the second known ship) to earth, also hidden among fragments of Krypton with two followers of General Zod.

In real life, the Earth has been struck by several surprise meteors since we have had the ability to track. Most of these burn up in atmosphere and are harmless but there are a rare few that are not, such as the [2013 Chelyabinsk meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelyabinsk_meteor). This is probably the most dramatic known one and its collision was not predicted to happen or even known about until it actually happened. This is a bit of a scary reminder that the gap in stellar object tracking is quite large, as we can only really detect them as they come close to the sun and heat up... otherwise they are so cold they are practically invisible. Though to put your mind at ease, Jupiter has a very good track record of catching most large asteroids in its gravity well before they become a problem for the inner planets.

One possible problem with this though is that the U.S. is not the most likely country to get hit by meteors. That honor falls to Russia... though this isn't a matter of God hating the godless commies, but the fact that Russia is the largest nation by land area. If any place with significant human population will get hit by a meteor, it will be Russia.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but the small size of the capsules, detecting them would be difficult. And if the capsules are even spotted, unless they adjust their courses, they will probably be believed to be some sort of meteorite-that is, until they land.

Comment: But wouldn´t it need to do so several times? 
I am NO expert in space flight, but i can´t imagine that, it would be able to get from the edges of our solar system to Earth without having to adjust its course a few times at the very least, to make sure it landed on Earth, near an inhabited zone. 
Simply drifting towards Earth and hope for the best would be a huge gamble, as it could either miss the planet all together, land in the ocean or in the middle of nowhere.
Either of those options would almost certainly mean death for infant inside the ship.

Comment: It will never be assumed to be a meteorite... meteorites are meteors that have struck the earth's surface.   As stated in my answer, tracking objects in space is difficult for us right now for anything not in the inner solar system because the surface is so cold it will blend in with the back ground).